# Is there an English word for someone who is *not* a little person or who doesn't have any dwarfism related disorders?

Tags: synonyms

Pretty much every minority group has words for people outside said minority group. For example: Gay & Trans people call outsiders "Cishet" (short for cisgender & hetersexual), Asexual people call outsiders "Allosexual," intersex people call outsiders "Dyadic," people of the Jewish faith call outsiders the "Goyim" or a "Gentile," Native Hawaiians calls outsiders "Haole," etc.

But I couldn't find one for people who are not little. The Little People of America website often refers to non-little people as "people of average stature" which is kind of a mouth full. Since my search didn't turn anything up, I thought maybe there isn't an official word for a non-little person but there could be a slang term little people use privately. That's not exactly what I'm looking for. So I came to this website to see if there is an official English word that little people use for non-little people and the "average stature" world in general.

If you don't know the answer directly, any helpful links would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think there is, no. If there were, I’d also rely on advocacy groups, as you have, and since that was a dead end (rather, a mouthful, as you say), I don’t hold out much hope. It may be that little people amongst themselves have a word for the “bigs”, but I suspect that, if they do, it’s not a word you’d want to use outside that context.

Comment: I think it's quite common for "out-groups" (recognisably different people who might wish to primarily associate with their own "kind") to refer to those who ***aren't*** in their group as ***normals / [normies](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+normies%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01GhWA0rcY15gGxKRQQ4rXJDYsjQw:1625398284827&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:p&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBwoq7qMnxAhVzQUEAHapCAuoQpwV6BAgBECA&biw=1492&bih=691&dpr=1.25)***. To my mind the term is at least *slightly* disparaging, when used in this way - which might explain why the gay community promoted ***straight*** over ***normal/ie***.

Comment: From the full OED: **normie** colloquial (originally U.S.). *A conventional or ordinary person, typically as contrasted with members of a specified group or subculture; spec. **an able-bodied person as contrasted with disabled people.*** I wouldn't want to say dwarves are "disabled", but I'm sure they'd count as typical "members of a specified group or subculture" for the purposes of that definition. I very much doubt there could be an "official" word for "normal people", because using any such term would be incredibly socially divisive.

Comment: Not calling the quest racist, but. There is the strong possibility that the treasure is a slur, as any label for *those guys* is likely less than loving. For example, Jews can claim that *goyim* literally means "nations," yet we are not so blind as not to see we also use it for *them!* --  dismissive if not actually rude or negative. I'm also thinking of Honkie, Gringo, and Muggles.

Comment: Maybe you can use any appropriate word but the first time you use it add a brief description. For instance “He was a regular person of full stature” and then just use the word ‘regular’ in future instances. Also, I’m not suggesting you use the word ‘regular’, that’s just a placeholder for the example because I can’t think of a more appropriate one right now.

Comment: Think about this for just a moment: "I thought maybe there isn't an official word for a non-little person"...official word?

Comment: 'Normie' doesn't work though, because 'Non-Little-Person' encompasses all of the rest of humanity, 'normal' or otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ on [Little People of Ontario](https://littlepeopleofontario.com/index.php?rt=product/category&path=64_79) uses 'Average-**Sized** People' which is a lot less of a mouthful, as does the LPA Spokeswoman in [this ABC article](https://abcnews.go.com/Health/world-dwarfism-dating-average-size-partners-accepted/story?id=17129298) it's also used in the LPA Bylaws.  So I think it's fair to say it's a well-accepted term in the community.

Answer (score 0):

> The terms usually preferred by people with this condition are "short-statured" or "little person" rather than "​dwarf."

From Verywell Health.com [The Most Commom Types of Dwarfism](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-many-types-of-dwarfism-are-there-2860725)

Although there are other developmental aspects, usually, regarding such conditions, it is true that shortness of stature is the most apparent and the above article uses the term 'short-statured' to embrace all the common forms.

I would suggest, therefore, that **'fully-statured'** would be a good description of persons not in the above category.

Perhaps 'over-statured' might be appropriate for the opposite condition.

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full+stature%2C+fully-statured&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfull%20stature%3B%2Cc0) for 'full stature' shows moderate usage but the term 'fully-statured' is not represented at all (yet).

=================================================================

EDIT after Comment : I have, as suggested, added 'full-statured' to the NGram and obtained some (very small) response for it.

Comment: What about "full-statured" (men, persons, etc)? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full-statured+%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfull%20-%20statured%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20men%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20strength%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20animal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfull%20-%20statured%20from%3B%2Cc0